# Android Java: Modification of instance variable inside button click handler

Tags: java, android

There is a strange behaviour of assigning/modifying instance variable of the class inside Button OnClick() handlers.

As shown below, the instance variable "CurrentFile" is modified inside imgBtn.setOnClickListener() handlers. But when this variable is accessed in onActivityResult() method, this variable contains the value "null".

According to my understanding, the activity "GetPicActivity" will not be destroyed till the Camera activity returns. So, the instance variable "CurrentFile" should not be null.

Please help, if I am missing some basics.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.favoritepics.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GetPicActivity extends Activity {

protected static final int ID_REQ_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
protected static final int ID_REQ_PICK_PHOTO = 0;
protected File currentFile = null;  /// Goal is "to modify this variable inside Button onClick handlers"

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.DKGRAY));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_pic);

    // set handler image gallery
    ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgGallery);
    imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // create intent to take picture on camera
            Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, ID_REQ_PICK_PHOTO);
        }
    });

    // set handler for camera image
    imgBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgCamera);
    imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File tempFile = null;

            try {

                currentFile = File
                        .createTempFile("_jpeg_", ".jpg", tempDir);

            } catch (IOException exception) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        GetPicActivity.this,
                        "Problem occured during creation of temp file! "
                                + exception.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (currentFile != null) {
                takePicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(currentFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePicture, ID_REQ_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            }
        }
    });

    // set handler for cancel button
    Button btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ID_REQ_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              Intent newIntent = new Intent();
              newIntent.putExtra("TYPE", requestCode);
              newIntent.putExtra("PATH", currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
              setResult(RESULT_OK, newIntent);
                finish();
           }

           break;

        default:
           break;
    }
  }
}
```

click here to see [Logcat messages](http://pastebin.com/MfUbpRS4)

Steps what I intend to do:

> 1, Create a temporary file in External storage for the destination of Camera picture
>
> 2, Start Camera to take a picture by passing the URI of temporary file
>
> 3, OnActivityResult() from camera,  return the (temporary) File path to previous activity for further process

But here what I see is,

**As soon as the Camera is started & picture is taken, the GetPicActivity is created again. Because of this, the instance variable "CurrentFile" will be null & in OnActivityResult() , I could not get the File path of temporary file.**

*Why is the GetPicActivity destroyed after starting Camera?*

Comment: I have added a link to logs

Comment: why u have finish() here..?

Comment: You mean the finish() inside `case ID_REQ_IMAGE_CAPTURE` ? I would like to return the result to the previous activity as soon as this activity gets a picture from Camera

Comment: i haven't tried with tempFile method. i think u should try once with simple file obj.

Comment: GetPicActivity destroyed after starting Camera? this is not possible. i am not having device for test camera code now otherwise i might tell u reason.

Comment: While debugging with emulator, I am seeing that the OnCreate() method of GetPicActivity is called once again after taking the picture from Camera. i.e., GetPicActivity is destroyed after starting Camera. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the camera is started, the Camera appears in the screen orientation "`Landscape`".

Even the orientation of already existing activity stack is changed to "`Landscape`" itseems.

So, When the result of Camera is returned to GetPicActivity method `OnActivityResult()`, the `GetPicActivity` is created again. But now, the instance variable "`CurrentFile`" is null. This, gives a `NullPointerException`.